# Angular 2: Using ngIf inside ngFor not working

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have the following `ngFor` loop:

```
<div *ngFor="let variety of varieties; let i=index">
    <div class="varietyTypeName">
        {{variety.VarietyTypeName}}            
    </div>
</div
```

Which prints out the following:

```
Greens
Greens
Greens
Fruits
```

I would like it to NOT print repeats, so instead (in this scenario), I would like it to print out:

```
Greens
Fruits
```

The `VarietyTypeNames` will always be grouped together in the array, so if there are multiple Greens, they will always come one after the other. Could I just use an `ngIf` inside of the loop and basically just tell it to only display the `VarietyTypeName` if it is NOT equal to the previous `VarietyTypeName`?

I tried implementing that logic below, but I'm getting an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div *ngFor="let variety of varieties; let i=index">
    <div *ngIf="variety[i].VarietyTypeName != variety[i - 1].VarietyTypeName" class="varietyTypeName">
        {{variety.VarietyTypeName}}
    </div>
</div
```

Here is the error message:

> Cannot read property 'VarietyTypeName' of undefined

Comment: I think @Gunter is right. You are using `let variety of varieties` but you are confusing it to the C-style for loop. You don't need index here, but if you want to use it then instead of `variety[i]` you should use `varieties[i]` as the latter is your collection, while former is an object in the collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
<div *ngFor="let variety of varieties; let i=index">
    <div *ngIf="variety.VarietyTypeName != varieties[i - 1]?.VarietyTypeName" class="varietyTypeName">
        {{variety.VarietyTypeName}}
    </div>
</div
```

Comment: This doesn't print out any instance of VarietyTypeName

Comment: I changed what you put to *ngIf="varieties[i]?.VarietyTypeName != variety[i - 1]?.VarietyTypeName" and it now works. What does the "?" mean/do?

Comment: @Brett I think this is the most elegant answer (although it has the bug you've already fixed).  The `object?.property` tells Angular to read the property only if the object is truthy (is not `null` or `undefined`)

Comment: @Brett yes exactly as already said by beetle `?` is called `elvis operator` which prevent angular to throw error if object or entry no found.

Comment: @PardeepJain I really liked your answer. It is much better than what I came up with!

Answer (score 2):

You should do that kind of logic inside your controller.

Filter all duplicates from the array and  then just simply iterate over it.

```
let filteredVarieties = varieties.filter((variety, index) {
    return varieties.indexOf(variety) == index;
});
```

Now you can `*ngFor` over that newly created `filteredVarieties`

Comment: Is performance better if I take care of it in the controller like you suggest?

Comment: I don't think there will be a big difference in performance. Our computers are strong enough to handle these little tasks quickly enough, so I suggest focusing on writing more readable code. You could wrap that `.filter` in a function called `removeDuplicates` and every new developer would understand at once what the code does.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it should be

```
<div *ngFor="let variety of varieties; let i=index">
    <div *ngIf="variety.VarietyTypeName != i == 0 ? 0 : varieties[i - 1].VarietyTypeName" class="varietyTypeName">
        {{variety.VarietyTypeName}}
    </div>
</div
```

Comment: This gives me that same error I was getting before.

Answer (score 0):

In such a situation, you may want to use a pipe to filter the values before iterating over them. I am going to demonstrate a simple pipe that may help. 
N.B I am going to use the library `lodash` to simplify the example.

`import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
    import * as _ from 'lodash';
    @Pipe({
        name: 'filter'
    })
    class FilterPipe {
        transform(input: any, term: any) {
            return _.uniqBy(input, term)
        }
    }`

After importing the pipe as you always would in angular 2, this is how you would have your template code

`<div *ngFor="let variety of varieties | filter : 'VarietyTypeName' ">
        {{variety.VarietyTypeName}}
    </div`

P.S Remember to add lodash to your vendor files.